# unnable to add particles.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem implementih particles.js to my website. I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined. 
i tried with the demo from the download site, there it is working, then i copyed the code from there and nothing on my site.

```js
/* -----------------------------------------------
/* How to use? : Check the GitHub README
/* ----------------------------------------------- */

/* To load a config file (particles.json) you need to host this demo (MAMP/WAMP/local)... */

particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function() {
  console.log('particles.js loaded - callback');
});


/* Otherwise just put the config content (json): */

particlesJS('particles-js',
  
  {
    "particles": {
      "number": {
        "value": 100,
        "density": {
          "enable": true,
          "value_area": 800
        }
      },
      "color": {
        "value": "#ffffff"
      },
      "shape": {
        "type": "circle",
        "stroke": {
          "width": 0,
          "color": "#000000"
        },
        "polygon": {
          "nb_sides": 5
        },
        "image": {
          "src": "img/github.svg",
          "width": 100,
          "height": 100
        }
      },
      "opacity": {
        "value": 0.5,
        "random": false,
        "anim": {
          "enable": false,
          "speed": 1,
          "opacity_min": 0.1,
          "sync": false
        }
      },
      "size": {
        "value": 5,
        "random": true,
        "anim": {
          "enable": false,
          "speed": 40,
          "size_min": 0.1,
          "sync": false
        }
      },
      "line_linked": {
        "enable": true,
        "distance": 150,
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "opacity": 0.4,
        "width": 1
      },
      "move": {
        "enable": true,
        "speed": 6,
        "direction": "none",
        "random": false,
        "straight": false,
        "out_mode": "out",
        "attract": {
          "enable": false,
          "rotateX": 600,
          "rotateY": 1200
        }
      }
    },
    "interactivity": {
      "detect_on": "canvas",
      "events": {
        "onhover": {
          "enable": true,
          "mode": "repulse"
        },
        "onclick": {
          "enable": true,
          "mode": "push"
        },
        "resize": true
      },
      "modes": {
        "grab": {
          "distance": 400,
          "line_linked": {
            "opacity": 1
          }
        },
        "bubble": {
          "distance": 400,
          "size": 40,
          "duration": 2,
          "opacity": 8,
          "speed": 3
        },
        "repulse": {
          "distance": 200
        },
        "push": {
          "particles_nb": 4
        },
        "remove": {
          "particles_nb": 2
        }
      }
    },
    "retina_detect": true,
    "config_demo": {
      "hide_card": false,
      "background_color": "#b61924",
      "background_image": "",
      "background_position": "50% 50%",
      "background_repeat": "no-repeat",
      "background_size": "cover"
    }
  }

);
```

```css
#stats{
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#particles-js{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/progress.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/particles.css">
    


</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-fixed-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
            &#9776;
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MS</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navbar1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#stage">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <!-- PARTICLES-->
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
   
   
   
   
   
    <div id="stage">
               <div id="stage-caption">
            <h1 class="display-3 fadeInDown animated ">
         THERE'S ONLY ONE MIHAEL SOBOČAN, WEB DESIGNER & PROGRAMMER!</h1>
            <p class="fadeInUp animated">
                WHEN YOU NEED RESULTS
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

   
    <section id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="section-content">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="about-text">
                            <h3>About Me</h3>
                            <p class="lead">
                                Hello, my name is Mihael Sobočan, i am a web designer & front-end web developer. My job is to build your website so that it is functional and user-friendly but at the same time attractive. 
                            </p>
                            <p>I love everything about the web, except Internet Explorer. I love creating new things with HTML5, CSS3, PHP and Javascript.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section-contenta">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1">
                        <div class="skills">
                            <p class="blured">My Skills</p>

                            <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="65%">
                                <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #d35400;"><span>
 <p class="blur">HTML</p></span></div>
                                <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #e67e22;"></div>
                                <div class="skill-bar-percent">65%</div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Skill Bar -->

                            <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="70%">
                                <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #2980b9;"><span>
 <p class="blur">CSS</p></span></div>
                                <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #3498db;"></div>
                                <div class="skill-bar-percent">70%</div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Skill Bar -->

                            <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="55%">
                                <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #2c3e50;"><span>
 <p class="blur">JAVA</p></span></div>
                                <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #2c3e50;"></div>
                                <div class="skill-bar-percent">55%</div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Skill Bar -->

                            <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="40%">
                                <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #46465e;"><span>
 <p class="blur">C++</p></span></div>
                                <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #5a68a5;"></div>
                                <div class="skill-bar-percent">40%</div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Skill Bar -->

                            <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="70%">
                                <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #333333;"><span>
 <p class="blur">BOOTSTRAP</p></span></div>
                                <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #525252;"></div>
                                <div class="skill-bar-percent">70%</div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Skill Bar -->

                            <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="1%">
                                <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #27ae60;"><span>
 <p class="blur">SINGING</p></span></div>
                                <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #2ecc71;"></div>
                                <div class="skill-bar-percent">1%</div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Skill Bar -->
                            <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="100%">
                                <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #27ae25;"><span>
 <p class="blur">9GAG</p></span></div>
                                <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #2ecc20;"></div>
                                <div class="skill-bar-percent">100%</div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Skill Bar -->





                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </section>


    <section id="feature-six" class="feature-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="feature-content">
             <div class="col-lg-6 hidden-md-down">
                 <img src="img/explorer.jpg" alt="explorer">
                 
             </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1">
               <p>I genuinely believe that all experiences - good and bad - can have a positive effect.</p>
               <img src="img/funny.jpg" alt="smile">
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
         
            
        </div> 
            
        </div>
            </section>

<footer id="main-footer">
    <div class="container">
      
      
      
       <div id="particles-js">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              &copy 2016 The original Webdesigner<br>
              Coded by Mihael Sobočan
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#stage">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
                    
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
             
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
</footer>


    <!-- Tether for Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/progress.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/particles.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `app.js` is the file which contains the JavaScript code you've pasted in your question, then here's the problem:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/progress.js"></script>
<!-- this file is included BEFORE particles.js! -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script> 
<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Instead, try

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/progress.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to load particles.js before you run the main code. You can do this by adding the `defer` tag to the script element.

```
<script src="mainScript.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

Replace `mainScript` with you script's filename

Answer (score 1):

Try to load particle.js before your script declaration

Comment: What does dichiaration mean?

Comment: app.js and particles.js. Try reverse the order

Comment: Okay, just you know, that word doesn't actually exist in english: https://www.google.hu/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dichiaration

Comment: Ahaha. Sorry "declaration" :)

Answer (score -1):

You must call the `particle.js` script file first, then call another scripts